# python get xml tag list

Tags: python, xml, tags

i have this xml file :

```
<root>
    <discovers>
        <discover>
            <zoulou>zag</zoulou>
            <yotta>bob</yotta>
            <alpha>ned</alpha>
        </discover>

        <discover>
            <beta>Zorro</beta>
            <omega>Danseur</omega>
        </discover>
    </discovers>
</root>
```

in python3.6 i want to get this output :

```
[[zoulou,yotta,alpha],[beta,omega]]
```

actually i can have all tag with this code in python

```
tree = etree.parse("./file.xml")
[elt.tag for elt in tree.findall("discovers/discover/*")]
```

i have this output :

```
['zoulou', 'yotta', 'alpha', 'beta', 'omega']
```

i don't found function for separate tag list by parent node, can you help me ?
i don't know how to separate my discover node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished by nesting list comprehensions. One option is to find all 'discover'-elements in the outer comprehension and then find any child elements.

```
[[ch.tag for ch in elt.findall('*')] for elt in doc.findall("discovers/discover")]

[['zoulou', 'yotta', 'alpha'], ['beta', 'omega']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve what you need, and in general on of the best ways to parse xml, is to use [BeautifulSoup4](http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/beautifulsoup/beautifulsoup-4-python):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


result = """<root>
    <discovers>
        <discover>
            <zoulou>zag</zoulou>
            <yotta>bob</yotta>
            <alpha>ned</alpha>
        </discover>

        <discover>
            <beta>Zorro</beta>
            <omega>Danseur</omega>
        </discover>
    </discovers>
</root>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(result, "lxml")

findName = lambda child: child.name
print [map(findName, x.findChildren()) for x in soup.findAll('discover')] # [['zoulou', 'yotta', 'alpha'], ['beta', 'omega']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `xml.etree.ElementTree`. It's a part of Python's standard library and provides a simple and efficient API for parsing XML.

Here is how you can use it:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_data = '''
<root>
    <discovers>
        <discover>
            <zoulou>zag</zoulou>
            <yotta>bob</yotta>
            <alpha>ned</alpha>
        </discover>

        <discover>
            <beta>Zorro</beta>
            <omega>Danseur</omega>
        </discover>
    </discovers>
</root>
'''

# Parse the XML data
root = ET.fromstring(xml_data)

# Extract the values
output = []
for discover_elem in root.findall('.//discover'):
    tags = [elem.tag for elem in discover_elem.findall('*')]
    output.append(tags)
    
print(output)
# [['zoulou', 'yotta', 'alpha'], ['beta', 'omega']]
```